# How to loop CSV file values using Ultimate Thread Group?

Tags: jmeter

I have this *links.csv* file:

```
METHOD,HOST,PATH,HITS
GET,google.com,/,7
GET,facebook.com,/,3
```

I want to create a JMeter test plan using [Ultimate Thread Group (UTG)](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) that randomize the hits based on the last column in the CSV above (HITS).

When viewing the results tree, I want to see something like this:

```
1. google.com
2. google.com
3. facebook.com
4. google.com
5. google.com
6. google.com
7. google.com
8. google.com
9. facebook.com
10. facebook.com
```

Ideally, I want to set the UTG to use the following settings:

- Start Threads Count = sum of all hits in the CSV file (e.g. 7 + 3)
- Initial Delay = 0
- Startup Time = 60
- Hold Load For = 30
- Shutdown Time = 0

How to achieve this? I appreciate code samples and screenshots since I'm still new to JMeter.

Comment: If you pass the Host name like ${url} to the sampler name, you can view the url name

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of generating a new CSV file out of your original one in order to:

1. Get the "sum" of "HITS"
2. Generate a line containing method, host and path per "hit"

In order to achieve this:

1. Add [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test/) to your Test Plan
2. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to the Thread Group
3. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def entries = new File('/path/to/original.csv').readLines().drop(1)
   def sum = 0
   def newCSV = new File('/path/to/generated.csv')
   newCSV << 'METHOD,HOST,PATH' << System.getProperty('line.separator')

   entries.each { entry ->
       def values = entry.split(',')
       def hits = values[3] as int
       sum += hits
       1.upto(hits, {
           newCSV << values[0] << ',' << values[1] << ',' << values[2] << System.getProperty('line.separator')
       })
   }

   props.put('threads', sum as String)
   ```
4. Use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like `${__P(threads,)}` in the Ultimate Thread Group
5. Use the new "generated" CSV file in the CSV Data Set Config in the Ultimate Thread Group

Comment: Hi, thank you for the idea. Do you mind sharing some screenshots for me? Thank you.